# webpack dev server replaces server.pem every 30 days?How do I make it pick my own cert ignoring the regenerated cert

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I have replaced webpack autogenerated `server.pem` with my own cert to run my react app SSL enabled.
Got to know that webpack regenerates and replaces the `server.pem` every 30 days which is causing error `NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

How do I make it pick my own cert ignoring the webpack generated certs?

I know I can write a script to replace it every 30 days or so but is there any better way to achieve this?